# matlab object detection and tracking

Tags: matlab

I m doing a research project on *"Object detection using my a digital camera"*. 
Some suggestion on how to build and program the Matlab code.
In particular, I have a picture of one object, say a screen of my laptop. Than I rotate the laptop and I shot a new picture. I would like to know the difference on the position of the screen. I think I can use the edge detection after a subtraction of the two images but... it is quite difficult for me to implement it.

Answer (score 12):

> Some suggestion on how to build and program the matlab code.

That largely depends on the goal you want to achieve. Can you be more specific? Are you streaming the frames or are you tracking offline?

> In particular, i have a picture of one object, say a screen of my laptop. Than i rotate the laptop and i shot a new picture. I would like to know the difference on the position of the screen.

There are many ways to do this, and an *extensive* litterature on the subject. I don't believe anyone would write up the equivalent of a survey paper on the subject as an answer  on StackOverflow. Why don't you get started with an object tracking survey paper and then ask a more precise question?

> hi, I m doing a reasearch project on "Object detection using my a digital camera". [...] I think i can use the edge detection after a subtraction of the two images but...is quite difficult for me to implement it.

What is your question? Are you asking us if this is a good way to track objects? Are you asking us if this is a new approach and has never been done? Are you asking someone to implement it for you?

Object tracking is a *hard* problem. I doubt that technique would succeed in any but the most basic scenarios. However, if you look at a survey paper, you might be pointed to a paper that already implemented this an presents results. Finally, I think you should brush up your programming skills because most (successful) object tracking techniques are not trivial to implement. If you don't want to program it yourself, there are online services where you can hire people. StackOverflow is not one of those places.

**EDIT**: I could deduce that you're new to *both* programming (in MATLAB) *and* in object tracking, hence in my answer. Don't mis-understand me, I'm trying to help. Let me re-phrase my suggestions as list:

1. **Your question is far too general**. You will get a lot more help from the SO community if you ask more precise questions for two reasons: A) general question result in general answers; and B) the way you asked your question could easily be interpreted as "someone, please do my work for me" even if that's not what you think you're asking.
2. **Get acquainted with the problem domain**. To ask more precise questions, you must be close to your answer. For good knowledge on the "object detection and tracking", find a good survey paper. If you're starting off on a research project, people in your lab should be of help to point you to a good one.
3. **Learn to program simple things first**. All of the most proficient (effective *and* efficient) programmers I've ever met struggled with the bubble sort when they were introduced to sorting. None of them would have been able to program an object detection algorithm as a first assignment. Get yourself a good [image processing book that has exercises in MATLAB](http://www.lavoisier.fr/notice/fr329707.html), go through execises one by one. If you can't do them all, choose those that are relevant to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Very much agree. It's indeed harder than it looks, but at least it provides me with a job :)

Comment: @Jonas: don't get me wrong, hard problems are the most fun :-) My point was to try and emphasize that it is an open problem for a good reason, and that if simple approaches succeeded, it wouldn't be a research topic any more!

Comment: I'm only at the beginning of programming and I was asking only a small suggestion to start and than procede by my self...

Comment: @vittorio: I summarised my suggestions as a list, take a good second look, it might be clearer now.

Comment: @Andre Caron: I understand, and I completely agree with your answer and suggestions.

Comment: Maybe i asked my question is a very bad way. Was not my intention ask someone to make my job for me. I really want to learn the art of programming but unfortunately i had to start with a non trivial problem - object tracking and detection. Just the suggestion you gave me about the book is more than sufficient. For this...thank you!

Comment: Anyway, i had an idea on who to solve my problem.  Let me show what i though....I have two pictures of a pc screen. One with the screen perfectly perpendicular to my camera and the second one with the screen rotated of a certain angle. My intention is to calculate the rotation angle. I don't know if it is possible but, i can say to matlab to rotate the second image until the sum(imhist(imsubtract(i2,i1))) > = 0. In this way, i think, i can obtain the angle of rotation.   I will try.... Still thank you for the help and the answer!