# Object detection in matlab

Tags: matlab, object, image-processing, detection

I want to write a code in matlab in which i would like to detect color objects in a given image and return the result as found the custom image or not found. i have an image of the custom object separately. im new to matlab... can anyone tell me how to proceed...

i have a pre defined image of an object say an lcd tv.... a given image which may or may not contain the object in it. i need a method to chek and find if the pre defined image is present or not in the given image... is it possible in matlab?

Comment: I suggest you start from the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156433/matlab-object-detection-and-tracking) and expand your question to explain what specifically you want to do.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, the question you're asking is an hugely complicated and still open research topic in machine learning and vision. It's not as simple as just convolving some kernel (of various sizes) with an image and scoring the responses. For example, a lot of things can have similar RGB appearance properties as an LCD TV. Without semantic information about the scene and object -- i.e. recognition classifiers from training data sets -- this is essentially not achievable. Try looking for freely available research code from vision researchers instead.

Answer (score 2):

The I suggest you start researching. Stack Overflow is not a great place to ask such generalized questions.

1) Anything that you can do in any programming language is possible in matlab, you are limited by three things:

a) How fast do you want it to work
b) how much coding do you want to do
c) how much of your memory is matlab going to eatup

2) If I am understanding your question correctly you are: Looking to match an image that is fit inside a larger image

Solution: shift your image across the other image, calulate the difference between all the pixels. The set of pixels that is closest to your desired image should be zero.